# object%20Object is prepending jQuery URL change

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to update the URL of a page onChange of a select list.

This is working except [object%20Object] is being added to the beginning and I can't figure out why.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('#filterType').on('change', function() {      
    var optionVal = $("#filterType option:selected").val();
    var parameter = "?cat="+optionVal;

    var url = $(this)+parameter;  

    if (url) {
        window.location = url;
    }
    return false;
}); });
```

The only solutions to this problem I can find are with AJAX and aren't relevant to my code.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are `$(this)` as prefix in url. which is jquery object of select element. You need to use `window.location.href` instead:

```
var url = window.location.href + parameter;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you. Can accept as an answer in 10minutes.

Comment: @BenToms: Sure. Glad it helps :)